# A Gaussian Divided by a Gaussian Equal to A Gaussian Divided by a Constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have a neural-network model in which each neuron is associated with an angle $\theta$.  Firing rate as a function of $\theta$ is either a Gaussian or a constant.

The claim has been made using this network that the *modulation ratio* is the same in two different conditions.  The modulation ratio is defined as

$$
\frac{f_A(\theta)}{f_B(\theta)},
$$

where $f_A$ and $f_B$ are two different firing rates across all $\theta$.

In condition 1, $f_A$ is a Gaussian, and $f_B$ is a constant.

In condition 2, $f_A$ is a Gaussian, and $f_B$ is also a Gaussian.

Is it possible that the modulation ratio is the same in these two conditions?  If it is possible, what does this imply about the relative widths of the different Gaussians?

Comment: If my memory serves, in your second condition, the ratio of two gaussian random variables is a Cauchy rv. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220436/the-probability-that-the-ratio-of-two-independent-standard-normal-variables-is-l

Comment: @Taylor thanks!  whereas the ratio of a gaussian and a uniform distribution is another gaussian (i think).  so i guess my question boils down to whether a gaussian distribution can ever be equal to a cauchy distribution.

Comment: no, but cauchy is a t distribution with 1 degrees of freedom. As the degrees of freedom goes to infinity thr t converges in distribution to a gaussian.